# Notifications only show last notification

Tags: macos, notifications

Under Mac OSX 10.13.2 my notifications list is only showing the last notification, not a list of the most recent. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my machine and the problem fixed itself.